# Using treaps tp solve RMQ

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree, time-complexity, binary-search-tree

I was trying to solve the following problem : [problem](http://www.spoj.com/problems/QMAX3VN/en/)

It is basically an RMQ problem with dynamically added elements. 
Ive tried using treaps (random priorities and the keys representing the indexes of the elements) to solve it, but it doesn't pass the time restrictions. If i've implemented it correctly, it should be O(log n) per query.

The code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>
#include<stdlib.h>    
#include<time.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string>
using namespace std;


typedef struct item * pitem;
struct item 
{
    int max; //max value in a tree
    int prior, value, cnt; //priority, value and the amount of nodes in a tree
    pitem l, r; //links to the left and right subtrees
};

int cnt(pitem it) //calculate the amount of nodes in a tree 
{
    return it ? it->cnt : 0;
}

int pmin(pitem it) //the max element in a tree
{
    return it ? it->max : -1e9;
}

void upd_cnt(pitem it) //updating cnt and max (assuming the subtrees' values have already been updates) 
{
    if (it)
    {
        it->cnt = cnt(it->l) + cnt(it->r) + 1;
        it->max = max(max(pmin(it->l), pmin(it->r)), it->value);
    }
}


void merge(pitem & t, pitem l, pitem r) //merging 2 trees with keys(l) < keys(r)
{
    if (!l || !r) //one of the trees is empty
        t = l ? l : r;
    //put the node with the most priority to the root of the new tree. we have 2 different cases
    //depending on which tree has the node with the highest priority
    else if (l->prior > r->prior)
    //the left node has higher priority. thus, the left subtree of the result is (tree->l->l) and the right is the result
    //of merging (tree->l->r) and (tree->r)
        merge(l->r, l->r, r), t = l;
    else
    //the symmetrical case
        merge(r->l, l, r->l), t = r;
    //recalculate the values. the values of the subtrees have been already
    //updated in the recursive calls
    upd_cnt(t);
}


//this is the modification of the split function where the keys are the indexes of the values in the array and thus are stored implicitly
//the current key of the element is equal to (tree->left->cnt) + sum(T->left->cnt + 1) where T is a pareent of the current tree such that the current tree
//lies in the right subtree of the parent.
void split(pitem t, pitem & l, pitem & r, int key, int add = 0) //split the tree into 2 trees: the left with keys <= key and the right with keys > key
{
    if (!t) //empty tree case
        return void(l = r = 0);
    int cur_key = add + cnt(t->l); //this helps us calculate the implicit key
    //the case where the node is in the lower subtree (key <= cur_key). Therefore, we need to split (tree->l)
    if (key <= cur_key)
        split(t->l, l, t->l, key, add), r = t;
    //the symmetric case
    else
        split(t->r, t->r, r, key, add + 1 + cnt(t->l)), l = t;
    upd_cnt(t);
}


//inserting an element after (pos) with (pvalue)
void insert(pitem &t, int pvalue, int pos)
{
    pitem l, r;
    //splitting the current tree by the position, obtaining 2 trees: one with keys <= pos and one with keys > pos
    split(t, l, r, pos);
    //create an item with 1 element
    pitem np = new item;
    np->cnt = 1;
    np->l = NULL;
    np->r = NULL;
    np->value = pvalue;
    np->max = pvalue;
    np->prior = rand() % 1000;
    //merging back. since keys(l) <= pos ans keys(r) > pos, the merge conditions are satisfied
    merge(t, l, np);
    merge(t, t, r);
}


//getting the maximum value in the range (l,r)
int getmin(pitem t, int l, int r)
{
    //first, we get the tree that contains the range (l,r). this is done by splitting out the keys (key < l) and then splitting out the keys (key > r)
    pitem t1, t2, t3;
    split(t, t1, t2, l);
    split(t2, t2, t3, r - l + 1);
    //getting the maximum value
    int ans = pmin(t2);
    //restoring the original tree. the merge conditions are satisfied by using the correct order of merging
    merge(t, t1, t2);
    merge(t, t, t3);
    return ans;
}


int main()
{
    ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    int n; scanf("%d", &n);
    srand(time(NULL));
    pitem pp = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        char c; scanf(" %c", &c);
        if (c == 'A')
        {
            int vl, ps;scanf("%d", &vl); scanf("%d", &ps);
            insert(pp, vl, ps - 1);
        }
        else
        {
            int l, r; scanf("%d", &l);scanf("%d", &r);
            --l, --r;
            cout << getmin(pp, l, r) << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there anything i've done wrong here? Is there any way to speed this up?

Comment: Use segment trees instead.

Comment: @IVlad Can i add an element to the array in any place using segment trees?

Comment: You can, but reading the problem and comments more carefully, you might not have to. Try using `fread` to read your data into a buffer and then parse the buffer.